# Golang: override initial elements of a slice

Tags: go, slice

I want to initialize an empty integer slice of length 3, store random ints in the slice, and sort the slice at each iteration. This code accomplishes that:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "sort"
)

func main() {
    myslice := make([]int, 3)
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        myslice = append(myslice, rand.Intn(100))
        sort.IntSlice(myslice).Sort()
        fmt.Println(myslice)
    
    }
}
```

End result: `[0 0 0 5 23 28 43 45 50 57 68 76 87]` However, I would also like to override the initial elements (in other words, get rid of those zeroes) before appending new elements. Since the slice is sorted at each iteration, calling `myslice[i] = rand.Intn(100)` if `i < 3` wouldn't necessarily work.

My initial solution is to write a function to get the first index of zero for `i < 3`, and replace that index with a new random value... however, I was wondering whether there is a better option to override the initial values of a slice.

Comment: If you know the values from the beginning you can specify those when creating the slice, using the `[]int{1,2,3}` syntax. https://play.golang.org/p/_0mAqB5rpP1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
myslice := make([]int, 0, 3)
```

to create a new `[]int` with length 0 and capacity 3. Though since you're appending more than 3 elements, this is fairly pointless; if you're going to preallocate, preallocate the whole thing, and if you're not going to preallocate the whole thing, just use `var myslice []int`.

[This is covered in the Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/13), which I highly recommend going through. It only takes a few minutes and covers all the language basics.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the suggestion of Adrian ,modifying the code as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "sort"
)

func main() {
    var myslice []int
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        myslice = append(myslice, rand.Intn(100))
        sort.IntSlice(myslice).Sort()
        fmt.Println(myslice)

    }
}
```

Output:

```
[81]
[81 87]
[47 81 87]
[47 59 81 87]
[47 59 81 81 87]
[18 47 59 81 81 87]
[18 25 47 59 81 81 87]
[18 25 40 47 59 81 81 87]
[18 25 40 47 56 59 81 81 87]
[0 18 25 40 47 56 59 81 81 87]
```